# How to configure the pool-size for a Message driven Bean in JBoss 6?

Tags: configuration, jboss, jboss6.x, message-driven-bean

I want to configure a bigger pool size for my message consumer in my java ee application, as the consumption of a message requires some time (mostly waiting).

How can i do this?
I would prefer a solution that uses annotation.

Is this task dependant on the used resource adapter? (mine is activeMQ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems like the jboss doesn't handle the mdb pool size by itself. The resourceadapter implementation of your jms broker does that.

For activemq the activeation-config-property is "maxSessions"
for hornetq (default) the property seems to be "MaxPoolSize"

another suggestion i found is to change this section in ejb3-interceptors-aop.xml

```
<annotation expr="!class(@org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.Pool)">
    @org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.Pool (value="StrictMaxPool", maxSize=15, timeout=10000)
</annotation>
```

although this would apply to every mdb (and also the @Pool annotation had no effect on my mdbs)